# Direct image of sheaves for blowing ups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety, $Z\subset X$ a smooth closed subvariety, and
$\pi:\tilde{X}\to X$ the blowing up of $X$ along $Z$. Let $E\subset\tilde{X}$ be the exceptional divisor, and $n$ an integer. Are there "formulas" for the sheaves $R^i\pi_*(\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(nE))$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute direct images for a blowing up?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445568/how-to-compute-direct-images-for-a-blowing-up)

Comment: I think the OP accidentally asked the same question twice in rapid succession. Since the other has an upvoted answer, I vote to close this one.