# How to compute direct images for a blowing up?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety, $Z\subset X$ a smooth closed subvariety, and
$\pi:\tilde{X}\to X$ the blowing up of $X$ along $Z$. Let $E\subset\tilde{X}$ be the exceptional divisor, and $n$ an integer. Are there "formulas" for the sheaves $R^i\pi_*(\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(nE))$?
Are there simple formulas?

Comment: Duplicate question https://mathoverflow.net/q/445565/88133

Answer (score 5):

Yes, sure, one can use inductively exact sequences
$$
0 \to 
\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}((n-1)E) \to 
\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(nE) \to 
\mathcal{O}_E(nE) \to 
0
$$
to prove that
$$
R\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(nE) \cong I_Z^{-n}
$$
for all $n \le 0$. Similarly, for $n \ge 0$ one can check that
$$
R^0\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(nE) \cong \mathcal{O}_X
$$
that
$$
R^i\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(nE) = 0
$$
for $1 \le i \le \mathrm{codim}(Z) - 2$, and
$$
R^{\mathrm{codim}(Z) - 1}\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(nE)
$$
is an explicit sheaf supported on $Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Apparently there are no general results about this.